# Generating FK constraints by matching column names

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, enterprise-architect

I have a database structure, which two tables `A` & `B`.

`A` contains few columns including a column `BiD` as a foreign key reference to the primary key of table `B`.

Issue is however columns are defined but `FK` constraints are not present. So I am looking for a way to generate these constraints through some automated method as the real database I am dealing with has over hundred tables.

My database is in Oracle 11g and I also have its ERD model available in Enterprise Architect. Solution in any of these would work. Please suggest if there is any such possibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`all_tab_columns` (or the `dba_` or `user_` version) will have column names and the table they're in.  If you simply want to find all columns named `BiD` and create a foreign key constraint to `B`, you could do something like

```
BEGIN
  FOR child IN (SELECT owner, table_name, column_name
                  FROM dba_tab_columns
                 WHERE column_name = 'BID'
                   and owner IN (<<schemas you care about>>))
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
      'ALTER TABLE ' || child.owner || '.' || child.table_name ||
      ' ADD CONSTRAINT fk_' || child.table_name || '_a FOREIGN KEY( bid ) ' ||
      ' REFERENCES b(bid) ';
  END LOOP;
END;
```

In a real system, you would probably want to have a local variable where you build up the SQL statement so you can log it before executing in case there is an error.  If you have case-sensitive identifiers or if the constraint name you would generate using this pattern would be more than 30 characters, you'd need to add logic to handle those cases.

Comment: He's probably after how to model in in EA rather than in Oracle.

Comment: @ThomasKilian - That's not how I read the question.  If you want EA to have the constraints but for the database not to enforce the constraints, you could create them as `RELY DISABLE NOVALIDATE`.  I would expect EA would import them although the database would not enforce them.

Comment: Maybe. So the question is: why is it tagged with Enterprise Architect. The tag should be removed if the question is not related to EA.

Comment: As i have written `Solution in any of these would work` whether EA or Oracle query based, both would work for me. If i can generate constraints directly over db i can import model and generate ERD in EA and if the solution is in EA i can generate SQL and run.